# python3-pygments is missing the executable

Tags: 18.04, python3, packaging

In 18.04 it seems the python3-pygments package is missing the pygmentize executable. That is, with python-pygments I can call pygmentize, but if I uninstall it and instead use python3-pygments, pygmentize is not available (nor under any other name AFAICT). How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to have python-pygments installed, and change the first line of `/usr/bin/pygmentize` to use python3. Not ideal, but it works.